# CSS class from FormType doesn't appear on page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig

I'm appending class attr to my field, but when I render the view instead of my class attr, I'm getting the `bootstrap-date`.

Here is my form field definition:

```
->add('startDate', 'date', [
            'label' => 'Start date',
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'advanced_search_form',
            ],
        ])
```

How I render form in twig-template:

```
{{ form_widget(search_form, {'attr': {'class': 'search_form'} }) }}
```

Comment: @xurshid29, I added twig, code.

Comment: @Panzer_Commander Replace 'class': 'search_form' with 'class' => 'advanced_search_form' in twig